# C++ Error I can't piece together: misunderstanding limits of data types?

Tags: c++, loops

Been working through LeetCode things as a supplement to get ahead before taking my intro course this term at university and as a way to pick up C++. I'm very comfortable with Python, but obviously working backwards here is rather difficult. At any rate, this algorithm seems like it should work, but, per the title, it isn't.

The parameter is an arbitrarily sized vector of 1's and 0's (`int`'s). The goal is to return the length of the longest string of 1's. For example, given `[1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]`, this function should return 3.

```
int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(vector<int>& nums) {
        int len = nums.size();
        
        int i;
        int temp = 0;
        int max, t2 = 0;
        
        for(i = 0; i<len; i++){
            if(nums[i] == 1){
                temp++;
            }
            if(nums[i] == 0){
                t2 = temp;
                temp = 0;
                if(t2 > max){
                    max = t2;
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
        
    }
```

When I submit this though, it fails on the test case `[1,0,1,1,0,1]`.

Rather than yielding the correct answer 2, it returns a seemingly random number far greater than 2 each time. Here are a few: 1834804276, 153863300, 928150512, ...

The only thing I can think of is issues with data types that are currently beyond my knowledge, but I'm beat. Appreciate any comments/ feedback.

Comment: You never initialize `max`.

Comment: And the shown algorithm is also fundamentally broken. If the vector consists of only 1s, the shown algorithm falls apart at its seams.

Comment: Well, that seems to have been it. Lack of syntax knowledge on my part then.

Comment: Not just syntax, but algorithmic too. Hint: it's not necessary to wait until a `0` in order to figure out if a new maximum of consecutive `1`s has been reached. This joyous occasion can be determined after every `1`.

Comment: Just woke up and redid it @SamVarshavchik. Your hint yielded a much cleaner result. Thank you! Realized I was able to do away with ```t2``` even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(vector<int>& nums) {
        int len = nums.size();
        
        int i;
        int temp = 0;
        int max = 0;
        
        for(i=0; i < len; i++){
            if(nums[i] == 1){
                temp++;
                if (temp > max){
                    max = temp;
                }
            }
            if(nums[i] == 0){
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

In response to Sam and Quentin's comments and for some closure if someone is looking at this. C++ does require you to actually initialize everything (something that was new to me coming from Python3). Like Sam had mentioned in a comment, checking for the largest string of 1's while adding to `temp` is a much wider umbrella. Thus, here is my accepted solution.